# Creating a Linked List via reading text from a File in a Loop C++

Tags: c++, file, text, linked-list

I have a homework assignment that requires me to create a linked list from a text file with two important caveats!

1. No arrays
2. No vectors

Really, I have some okay understanding of linked lists, but I seem to be failing myself somewhere in my program. Often, I'm getting these ERROR codes like an inability to access traverse->next Node. I often check for traverse->next node in order to traverse my linked list.

Right now, I'm not receiving any error codes. I have a cout statement in my linked list to show me that the traverse node is at least (at one point) equal to my text file's output. It displays the correct information inside the while loop, but when I go to print it.... the information disappears.

My best guess is that my program is not linked my list properly. However, if that's the case, I haven't been able to figure out how to properly link them.

Can someone give me a hint or some advice on this? It's really the first part of the assignment (hence "InitList()" function name) but I'm struggling to get it to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


struct Node
{
    string fName;
    string lName;
    double hours;
    double pay;
    int unionCode;
    int id;

    Node *next;

}; Node *head = nullptr;

//standard node struct with a global root node so I don't have to pass it everytime


void InitList();
void AddRecord();
void PrintList();

//prototypes



int main()
{

    InitList(); 

    PrintList();

    int options;

    cout << "MENU\n" <<
        "______________________________\n" <<
        "1: Add a Record\n" <<
        "2: Modify a Record\n" <<
        "3: Display a Record\n" <<
        "4: Display a Summary\n" <<
        "5: Display File\n" <<
        "6: Exit Program\n" << endl;

    cin >> options;


    switch (options)
    {
        case 1:
            AddRecord();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}

void AddRecord()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("PATH.txt", ios::app);

    file.close();


}

void InitList()
{
    //initializes the linked list from here on out, all changes made are    
    //reflected on the list 
    //and the text doc until the program quits

    fstream file;
    file.open("PATH.txt");

    Node *add;
    Node *traverse = head; //set traverse pointing to head


    while (file.good()) //I realize this isn't ideal, but it's temporary to get it working
    {

        add = new Node;

        file >> add->fName
            >> add->lName
            >> add->id
            >> add->pay
            >> add->hours
            >> add->unionCode;

        add->next = nullptr;

        if (traverse)
        {
            while (traverse->next)
            {
                traverse = traverse->next;
            }

            traverse->next = add;
            cout << traverse->fName << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            head = add;
            cout << head->fName << endl;
        }
    }
    file.close();

}


//simple Printing function... this is that part that's printing out ONLY the head value and nothing else (hence my assumption that head isn't linked)
void PrintList()
{
    Node *traverse = head;

    while (traverse->next)
    {
        cout << traverse->fName << " " << traverse->lName << " " << traverse->id << " $" << traverse->pay << " " << traverse->hours << " " << traverse->unionCode << endl;

        traverse = traverse->next;
    }

}
```

Comment: What a second... could I create a while loop... pass the node to a simpler add function and then add the node to the list there? That seems easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (file.good())
{
    Node *add = new Node;

    file >> add->fName >> add->lName >> add->id >> add->pay >> add->hours >> add->unionCode;
    add->next = nullptr;

    InitList(add);

}
```

This is how I fixed it (CODE LOCATED IN INT MAIN()). Basically, I transfer data into Node *add and then pass it to a normal linked_list add function. I pass it by reference. Can someone explain why it wouldn't work before? I'm guessing it has to do with the value of "traverse" not being reset to "head" like I'm used to doing. How else could I have fixed this?

When creating a linked list in a loop, is it better to use iterative functions and pass traverse, iterate a function like I did, or use a complex system of nested loop like I FAILED to do?